# Simplify circular generic constraints in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given the following base classes:

```
public abstract class PurchaseSystemControllerBase<TController, TViewModel> : IInitializable
    where TController : PurchaseSystemControllerBase<TController, TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<TController, TViewModel> {

    protected TViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    ...
}

public abstract class PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<TController, TViewModel> : ViewModelBase
    where TController : PurchaseSystemControllerBase<TController, TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<TController, TViewModel> {

    protected TController Controller { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

Concrete implementations are as follows:

```
public sealed class PurchaseSystemController : PurchaseSystemControllerBase<PurchaseSystemController, PurchaseSystemViewModel> {
    ...
}

public sealed class PurchaseSystemViewModel : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<PurchaseSystemController, PurchaseSystemViewModel> {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this so that the following is possible?

```
public sealed class PurchaseSystemController : PurchaseSystemControllerBase<PurchaseSystemViewModel> {
    ...
}

public sealed class PurchaseSystemViewModel : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<PurchaseSystemController> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you should try to avoid this sort of self-referencing generic when possible (though it does have its uses). Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately not - at least, not that I'm aware of, without losing some type safety.
I have a very similar set-up in [my Protocol Buffers port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/), between the message type and its corresponding builder type.

If you'd be happy declaring the `ViewModel` and `Controller` properties with just some non-generic base types, then that's fine - but if you need the two to know the corresponding types exactly, you're left with this sort of mess.

(You might want to consider whether the ViewModel and Controller *should* both know about each other, mind you.)

Comment: `not that I'm aware of` If Jon Skeet is not aware of it then it is confirmed for us guys :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible while keeping the fully-strong typing that you have. Here's an example of how you might reduce it to a more basic typing:

```
public abstract class PurchaseSystemControllerBase : IInitializable {
    protected PurchaseSystemViewModelBase ViewModel { get; private set; }
}
public abstract class PurchaseSystemControllerBase<TViewModel>
                    : PurchaseSystemControllerBase
    where TViewModel : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase {
    // note: property implementations should prevent this and base.ViewModel
    // from getting out of sync
    protected new TViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class PurchaseSystemViewModelBase : ViewModelBase {
    protected PurchaseSystemControllerBase Controller { get; private set; }
}
public abstract class PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<TController>
                    : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase
    where TController : PurchaseSystemControllerBase {
    // note: property implementations should prevent this and base.Controller
    // from getting out of sync
    protected new TController Controller { get; private set; }
}


public sealed class PurchaseSystemController
                  : PurchaseSystemControllerBase<PurchaseSystemViewModel> {
}
public sealed class PurchaseSystemViewModel
                  : PurchaseSystemViewModelBase<PurchaseSystemController> {
}
```

This might be sufficient, especially considering these are `protected` properties.